Cell to display dollar amount if a number amount is entered in same cell
Shed Materials List:

What I am trying to do is if I enter the amount of 2x4x8's for trusses (20) in cell AD9, I want excel to multiply the amount entered in cell AD9 (20) by the dollar amount in cell AA9. Then display the summed dollar amount in the same cell (AD9). Thanks in advance!

You can't make excel overwrite a value if you enter something. You can place a formula that calculates it in an adjacent cell though, and you can make a macro that if you click a cell, it gives a popup to enter a value, then after you press ok, calculate what it should be, and enter that in the cell. But if you do it any differently, the macro would constantly change the value of all your cells.

You can use a macro which responds to change event in column AD e.g.:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> Range("AD1").Column Then Exit Sub
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target.Offset(, -3)
        If IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value > 0 Then
            .Copy
            Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply
        End If
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

The macro code must be placed in the sheet module.
